# Authorize.net changes

Tags: authorize.net

I received a notice from authorize.net telling of changes to the interface. I did not see any comments so I thought I would ask the question. Does the connections to civicrm require any updates because of:

- Akamai SureRoute
- Transaction and Batch ID
- RC4 Cipher Disablement

Comment: Thanks for asking... I have the exact same questions...  I'm hoping these changes won't break anything?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a *full* answer, but ... I just had to research this same thing for a client.

1. Check that your processor config is using the correct URLs:
   http://www.authorize.net/support/akamaifaqs/#newurls

/civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?reset=1

2. Even in our client's old version of CiviCRM, the transaction ID field is 255 characters.
3. The cipher suite is a question for your host. A good host *should* be using modern cipher suites and disallowing insecure ones.
4. Not sure about requiring sequential transaction ID ... have not done a CiviCRM code audit to make sure (yet). Don't see why it would, but who knows.

Comment: You can use https://www.ssllabs.com to check the cipher suites.

Answer (score 2):

See [CRM-16928](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16928), a pull request on CiviCRM 4.6 to update `core/xml/templates/civicrm_data.tpl`. It is marked as fixed/completed as of 4.7.

Comment: Thanks for the post. It would be helpful for others if you could provide a direct link to this.